# What does the empty strings in regular expressions give?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this following line of code for which I'm not quite sure the output would be. I have found out that `sys.path` has the first index as an empty string. I think this means add `path1/path2` to the `sys.path` but not sure why do I need `' '` for? I'm using python 2.7. Thanks!

```
extracting_paths = re.findall('.*path1/path2/.*', ' '.join(sys.path))
```

Comment: Why not run the code and inspect the output?  What do you get?

Comment: Unfortunately cannot run the code now due to technical reasons :( sorry.

Comment: try to look up the docs for re.findall

Comment: There are a lot of online python compilers you could use the only thing you need is access to the internet

Answer (score 0):

`re.findall(pattern, string)` finds all the occurrences of `pattern` in `string`.

The string is in this case built by using [`.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and result in one big string with all list entries from `sys.path` joined by a space.

You need this space because otherwise all paths in `sys.path` would be joined together into one big path string...

Answer (score 0):

the `' '.join(sys.path)` part joins the paths into one string delimited by `' '` then the `.*` parts in your regular expression in `findall()` matches this whitespace delimiter as well.

so you can do this instead:

```
extracting_paths = re.findall('[^\s]+path1/path2/[^\s]+', ' '.join(sys.path))
```

in case your paths also have whitespaces (this is better):

```
extracting_paths = re.findall('[^:]+path1/path2/[^:]+', ':'.join(sys.path))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extracting_paths = re.findall('.*path1/path2/.*', ' '.join(sys.path))
```

Should actually rather than concatenating the pathnames and then matching should match on each pathname seperately:

```
pat = re.compile('.*path1/path2/.*')
extracting_paths = filter(pat.match, sys.path)
```

If you want strings and the locations of the matches in each string that has a match one could use

```
extracting_paths = filter(lambda t: t[1], zip(sys.path, map(pat.findall, sys.path)))
```

Both of these are safer as they don't assume an in-band delimiter.